# Keyboard sending completely different scan codes

Tags: keyboard

A few days ago I have dismantled my laptop, but after fixing one issue another one popped out. The keyboard sends completely different scan codes, and I mean really. `a` became `;`, `d` became `enter`, `space` became `backspace` and so on. I've checked scan codes using `evtest` and there are some keys clusters that do not send anything, like `j k o` and numpad `4568`. The issue is present on Linux, Windows and in BIOS

I've reconnected the keyboard tape many times, cleaned the tape endings, dedusted everything, but no luck. Tape does not have any visual damage, connector also seems fine and holds the tape firmly. Shaking and tapping the keyboard does not work, same with flexing the tape during typing.

The strange thing is that after second tape plug-out and plug-in it started working correctly, so I put everything together just to see it broke again.

External keyboard works fine. It looks like some internal keyboard damage, but I'm not sure, maybe something on motherboard got fried by static discharge. Is it possible, or replacing the keyboard will surely do the trick? I'm not able to test the keyboard on any other device.

Notebook is MSI GE60 0NC

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the keyboard has failed.  Unfortunately, the only way to test is to get a replacement keyboard.  More than likely a trace in the ribbon cable is broken, but its impossible to say.  Go to the manufacturer's website and order a replacement.

Comment: Should it be possible to plug this keyboard to another laptop? IIRC this one has a 26 pin, is it a standard?

Comment: @Zbyszekkxy Honestly, I do not know.  They may be standard by the keyboard manufacturer.  I dont believe they are standard across the board.  I would not plug in a ribbon cable to a laptop its not designed for, as it is possible but not likely, to cause damage.